# Set control div to bottom of page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to set up a bottom control div which will contain buttons. This control div will be stuck to the bottom of the page like a bottom navbar or footer. I'm using Bootstrap so my control container div is using Bootstrap's "row" class. To get it to stick to the bottom of the page I set the bottom to 0 and the position to fixed. However, when I do this, combined with the width being 100%, the right side of the control container div extends all the way to the far right of the page. How do I get this bottom div to line up with the big white box above it, complete with the margins on left and right?

Here is the code for the bottom control div:

```
<div class="row" style="background-color: darkgray; bottom: 0; position: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="button" class="btn" value="Add" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="button" class="btn" value="Delete" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="button" class="btn" value="Save" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is something like the picture below but have the control div be stuck to the bottom of the page.

[image]

Comment: did you try position: absolute, right: 0, bottom: 0 ?

Comment: @x-magix, I just tried that and it extended the left side out all the way to the left of the page. >.<

Comment: if you are looking for second of your picture then remove position and width (if you are using bootstrap). Tell me than

Comment: Everything about the 2nd picture is perfect but the location. I'd like it to be stuck to the bottom of the page like a bottom navbar or footer.

Answer (score 0):

ok then you do it like this

1. remove class 'row'
2. change your code as follow

.

```
<div style="left: 0; bottom: 0; position: fixed; width: 100%;">
      <div style="background-color: darkgray; width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; display: block;">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="button" class="btn" value="Add" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="button" class="btn" value="Delete" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="button" class="btn" value="Save" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That code produces this: https://i.imgur.com/y07NABR.png.